# Unit testing a domain with transient property

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to unit test a controller for User domain generated by Spring Security Core Plugin. The controller was generated with grails generate-all. 
The domain has a transient property called springSecurityService. In my unit test I am trying to mock that service and assign this transient variable to my mocked version. However, I get this error :

```
No such property: springSecurityService for class: com.myapp.security.SecUser Possible solutions:
springSecurityService groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: springSecurityService for class: 
com.myapp.security.SecUser at com.myapp.security.SecUserControllerTests.setUp(SecUserControllerTests.groovy:26)
```

Here is my domain look like:

```
class SecUser {
    transient springSecurityService
    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    ....
    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }
    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

Here is how my test look like:

```
 package com.myapp.security

 import org.junit.*
 import grails.test.mixin.*
 import com.myapp.system.*
 import grails.plugins.springsecurity.*

 @TestFor(SecUserController)
 @Mock([SecUser,SpringSecurityService])
 class SecUserControllerTests {

    @Before void setUp() { 
       def service = mockFor(SpringSecurityService)
       service.demand.encodePassword(1..2) { a -> return 'd3jk3j4ls234'}
       def control = service.createMock()
       SecUser.springSecurityService = control
   }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong or even I can even do something like this with transient property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a mockup situation, See if this works:

```
@Before void setUp() { 
    def service = mockFor(SpringSecurityService)
    // using the groovy MetaClass runtime
    service.metaclass.encodePassword = {def a -> 'd3jk3j4ls234'}
    SecUser.springSecurityService = service
}
```

or a more static solution:

```
@Before void setUp() { 
    secUser.springSecurityService = [
        encodePassword : {def a -> 'd3jk3j4ls234'}
    ] as SpringSecurityService
}
```

Comment: with couple of tweaks your solution also fixed the no method found, but still the overriding the service method does not work and I get "cannot get method on null object" because the mocked service is null.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign your mocked `springSecurityService` to the `SecUser` *class* (as if it were a static), which won't work when it's an instance variable. I'm not an expert on the new Grails 2 testing annotations but I believe that if you replace

```
SecUser.springSecurityService = control
```

with

```
SecUser.metaClass.getSpringSecurityService = {-> control}
```

then it should do what you want.

Comment: Ian, thanks for the reply, with your solution I can get the hold of the service, but still is failing in mocking it. seems im failing to mock the springsecurityservice encodepassword method.

Comment: Maybe a combination of the two answers then - `SecUser.metaClass.getSpringSecurityService = {-> [ encodePassword: {a -> 'fixedvalue'} ] }`