# How do I mock a transient service in my domain?

Tags: grails, spock

I am using Grails 2.4.4. I have a domain with a transient service defined like so:

```
class CustomField {

    transient myRepoService
    // other properties here

    static transients = [
        'myRepoService'
    ]

    static constraints = {
        name validator: { val, obj ->
            if (obj.nameExists(val)) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    protected boolean nameExists(String name) {
        MyInfo info = myRepoService.currentRepo.info
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

I would like to test it in Spock. I have tried various solutions but they don't work. Here are the methods I tried:

```
def myRepoService = mockFor(MyRepoService)
myRepoService.demand.currentRepo = { -> Myinfo.build() }

CustomField customField = new CustomField(name : 'hulk')
customField.myRepoService = myRepoService.createMock()
```

this one gave me an error even if I added an `@Mock([MyRepoService])` annotation:

```
|  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add Domain class [class com.myapp.MyRepoService]. It is not a Domain!
```

I also tried to use MetaClass like so:

```
def service = mockFor(myRepoService)
service.metaclass.currentRepo = { -> MyInfo.build() }
CustomField.currentRepo = service
```

but it just gave me some `NullPointerException` saying that my MyRepoService is null or something like that.

I've looked through this thread : ([Unit testing a domain with transient property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272041/unit-testing-a-domain-with-transient-property)) as well, to no avail.

How do mock this service properly so that I could test my custom validator? I'm starting to lose my patience on this.

Comment: Please elaborate on "or something like that".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of unit test class for your case :

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@Mock(CustomField)
class MyRepoServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def "test"() {
        given: "mock"
        def serviceMock = Mock(MyRepoService) // Spock mocking
        serviceMock.getCurrentRepo() >> { Myinfo.build() }
        CustomField customField = new CustomField(name : 'hulk')
        customField.myRepoService = serviceMock

        when: "validating field"
        def isValid = customField.validate()

        then: "validation pass"
        isValid == true
    }
}
```